# Integration Bus adding external jar exception

Tags: java, apache, websphere, ibm-mq, ibm-integration-bus

So I am trying to connect to FTPClient from my JavaCompute node in Integration Bus v10.0.0.8. 
The problem occurs because my runtime don't see the imported jar. 
Exception that happens :

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I would use the IIB built-in File Read node and configure the FTP section to fetch a remote file.

Comment: Yes I agree with @DanielSteinmann and would go further in saying you are taking a risk. IIB has its own management strategies for I/O and threads and you can buy yourself quite a bit of trouble if you interfere with that. You'll probably get away with but do think long and hard because the time you are most likely to get bitten is during an upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

You probably did not add the JAR files as dependencies of the Java project in your Toolkit.

- Create a `lib` subdirectory in your Java project and copy the JAR files there.
- Right click the Java project, Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries
- Click button `Add JARs...` and add the libraries from the `lib` directory.

See also the [Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac30280_.htm).

To read a file from an FTP server, you can also use the [File Input](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac55150_.htm) or [File Read](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/bc34090_.htm) nodes and configure the FTP section. In case you use SFTP, please look at [IT23379](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IT23379) as well.

Comment: I did that, but that does not affect my runtime , so instead i had to put the jar in > 
C:\<instalation folder>config\OracleDatabase\shared-classes

Comment: Yes, that works as well. But then it makes deployments more difficult. It is a lot nicer if the JAR files are included in the BAR file. Can you post the output of mqsireadbar -b <your-bar-file> -r? It should contain the JAR files; if it doesn't, you did not follow the steps correctly.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that my RUNTIME did not see the jar (hence the exception) and what i did was that i imported the jar in shared-classes folder:

C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQSI\config\OracleDatabase\shared-classes